# Comparator function for sorting a vector pair in descending order by first element (contains duplicates) and the resulting vector is stable

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I need to sort a vector of pairs in descending order based on the first element of the pair. If the first element of the pair is equal then the comparison is based on second element, the one with the less values of the second pair element must come first.
Ex: if pair is (0,0), (2,1), (1,2) then result must be (2,1), (1,2), (0,0). (2nd element of pair is array idex to make the array stable after sorting).

I have written following comparator function as following

```
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first > b.first) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.first == b.first) {
        if (a.second < b.second) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the above input I am getting the following output.
(1,2), (2,1), (0,0) but I am expecting the output described above, the same function is producing desired result in some other cases. What is wrong with this comparator function?

I am calling it as

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

where v is a vector of pairs.

```
vector <pair<int, int> > v;
```

Comment: `return true;` and `return false;` are better for `bool` function

Comment: You should have gotten a warning about not all code paths have a return.

Comment: Hint: You don't have to write much code: [`std::pair` comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp), [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your comparison algorithm is for case when `a.first < b.first`. You must rewrite the logic for something like:

```cpp
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first == b.first) {
        return (a.second > b.second);
    } else {
        return (a.first > b.first);
    }
}
```

Comrarison for `second` is used only when `first` are equal, so first check the first with `==`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't handle in your code the case where `a.first < b.first`. A complete version would be:

```
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first > b.first) {
        return true;
    } else if (a.first < b.first) {
        return false;
    } else { // a.first == b.first
        if (a.second < b.second) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first == b.first) {
        if (a.second < b.second) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (a.first > b.first) {
            return true;
        } else if (a.first < b.first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be simplified into:

```
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first == b.first) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    } else {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
}
```